# Unambiguous Grammar

Tags: parsing, recursive-descent

I want to create an unambiguous grammar for arithmetic expressions. Now the exponentiation should be of higher precedence and associate to the right. All other operations associate to the left. This is what I have so far but I don't know if the exponentiation is correct

```
E -> E+T | E-T | T
T -> T*F | T/F | L
L ->  F^ L|F
F -> i | (E)
```

Comment: Yes it is. I don't think it makes any difference but I updated the tittle.

Comment: @user1072706 : it makes a difference because we *try* not to spoil homework problems (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Also, we ask that you show us what you've tried (which you've done).

Comment: I would suggest you simulate your parser by hand on `1-2-3/4/5^6^7-8-9`. That exercises your precedence rules fairly well and exposes associativity issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am curious, because this is tagged recursive-descent, which makes me think LL.

When creating a grammar for an LL parser, remember these rules.

Repetition is used for left associativity:

```
Foo -> Bar (op Bar)*
```

Tail recursion is used for right associativity:

```
Foo -> Bar (op Foo)?
```

Now, you don't have an LL-parser-friendly grammar because you have left recursion:

```
E -> E+T
```

On the other hand, if it were LL, your exponentiation uses tail recursion, so that would work.

I suggest wikipedia's [Top Down Parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_parsing) and [Left-Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) articles (these are easier reads than the [LL parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parsing) article). And note, [LR parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) work different, and result in different grammars for left and right associativity.

Oh, and your rule ordering is correct for what LL parsers need for precedence. Your lower-precedence operator rules come first in the production rule chain.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your grammar, here is a more readable version of what you *want*.  It is unambiguous and correctly captures associativity.

```
expr -> term | expr add term
term -> factor | term mult factor
factor -> number | - factor | ( expr )
add -> + | -
mult -> * | /
```

This example should be much more readable so that you can apply this to your homework.  I did leave out the `^` operator but you should be able to figure it out from the example.  If you care to buy [another] textbook, [Programming Language Pragmatics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123745144) is of great help.